# Google Plus button not working in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus, xcode6

I have been following [Fernando's blog on integrating Google+ authentication with Swift iOS here:](https://medium.com/swift-programming/google-in-swift-a0943352dfe9)

I have am having a little trouble getting the button to work properly. I have created a UIButton in the storyboard, and associated the class `GPPSignInButton` with it.

However, when I do select the button, Xcode throws out the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   ‘NSInvalidArgumentException’, reason: You must specify [clientID] for
>   [GPPSignIn].

I have specified my `clientID` in ViewController as `signIn?.clientID = “myclientID”`. Is there anywhere else I should have specified the `clientID`?

Sorry for the super newb question, I do **c#** on a daily basis, but I am very new to Swift, Xcode, Apple...etc.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to be sure you have instantiated the singleton of the SingIn class:

```
let GoogleSignIn:GPPSignIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
```

Then, you must include your ClientID, scope, delegate properties and GoogleSignIn.authenticate() method in order to complete the first part of the Authentication flow.

Other possible solution is to be sure you have connect your button as an IBoulet

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GPPSignInButton!
```

Comment: I have edited all the code, and also included the 'IBOutlet' snippet. Still receiving the same error as before, about clientID not being specified. Do you happen to have a sample project I could debug? I am looking at Fernando's code and I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing also happened to me. I just change button type System to Custom. It will show. try it..!!